# MultinormalDistribution not having the right mean

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, vector

I am using the function `MultinormalDistribution` to generate a random vector using the following code:

```
RandomReal[
 MultinormalDistribution[
  c03 ConstantArray[
   1, {Binomial[n, 2], Binomial[n, 2]}] + (1 - 
     c03) IdentityMatrix[Binomial[n, 2]]]]
```

Here `c03 = 0.959016` and `n = 100` so the covariance matrix is very large. To check the resulting random vector, I plugged it into `Histogram` to see if it made sense. The histogram is a bell curve like it should be, but its mean is not the theoretically predicted zero. In fact, every time I run my code I get a histogram with the same shape but with a different mean which ranges as far as -1 to 1. However, if I generate a random vector of the same length using

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], Binomial[n,2]]
```

it has the correct mean of about zero without fail. Am I using `MultinormalDistribution` incorrectly? Are these errors because the covariance matrix is so big? I really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Lots of missing stuff. Can you give typical values for `c03`, `c13`, and `undirectedlist`?

Comment: In my case c03 = c13 = 0.959016 so actually the sparse array with undirectedlist doesn't matter. However undirectedlist is a list of pairs of indices of length 6Binomial[n,3] = 970200 and is such that the sparse array is symmetric.

Comment: Then why did you not give the simpler example to begin with? Please include this additional information in your post by [editing it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/159168/edit). In any event: `RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[ToeplitzMatrix[Prepend[ConstantArray[c03, Binomial[n, 2] - 1], 1]]]]`

Comment: Also, your guess about the ill-conditioning seems to be correct: ``With[{c03 = 0.959016, n = 100}, LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[ToeplitzMatrix[Prepend[ConstantArray[c03, Binomial[n, 2] - 1], 1]]]]`` gives `231612.`.

Comment: I increased the precision in the computation and now the results are making sense. Thanks!